# Is a topological space without cut points connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I'm trying to prove that having a cut point is a topological invariant, and my proof hinges on this claim that a space without cut points is connected, but I haven't proved this claim yet, so I'm not sure if it is true. I continue to contemplate...

Comment: $X = \{\hspace{-0.02 in}0,\hspace{-0.04 in}1\hspace{-0.03 in}\} \;\;\;$ and $\;\;\; \mathcal{T} \: = \: \big\{\hspace{-0.03 in}\{\},\hspace{-0.04 in}\{0\},\hspace{-0.04 in}\{\hspace{-0.02 in}1\hspace{-0.02 in}\},\hspace{-0.04 in}\{\hspace{-0.02 in}0,\hspace{-0.04 in}1\hspace{-0.03 in}\}\hspace{-0.03 in}\big\} \;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: The space consisting of two discrete points has no cut points.

Comment: Oh If course. I thought it was too simple to be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely a space without cut points isn't necessarily connected. Take for instance $]0,1[\cup]2,3[\subset\mathbb{R}$ with Euclidean topology. In fact, any not connected space does not have any cut points, since cut points are only defined for connected spaces.

For the actual proof:

Note that if $X$ has a cut point $x$, and $X$ is homeomorphic to some other space $Y$ by the homeomorphism $f$, then since $X$ is connected, $Y$ is connected. Now $X-\{x\}$ is homeomorphic to $Y-\{f(x)\}$. Since $X-\{x\}$ is not connected, $Y-\{f(x)\}$ is not connected, hence $f(x)$ is a cut point of $Y$.

Comment: Ok that kind of makes sense to me. I just have to convince myself that X-{x} is homeomorphic to Y-{f(x)} and that disconnectedness is topologically invariant.

Comment: Ok, I am ok with disconnectedness.

Comment: Well a continuous function restricted to a subspace will still be continuous. When we restrict $f$ to map from $X-\{x\}$ to $Y-\{y\}$ it will also still be bijective, and the restrictions $f$ and $f^{-1}$ will still be continous. And since connectedness is a topological property, so is disconnectedness.

Comment: Ok, I guess my trouble is realizing how the subspace topology is defined and making the connection between X-{x} and Y-{f(x)}.

Comment: A "new open" in y will be of the form $U-\{y\}$ where $U$ is an "old open". Now $f^{-1}(U-\{y\})=f^{-1}(U)-f^{-1}(\{y\})=f^{-1}(U)-\{x\}$ is open in $X-\{x\}$.

Comment: Oh ok, so that makes f restricted to X-{x} a homeomorphism with codomain Y-{f(x)}.

Comment: Exactly. (Note that by the same argument f is still continuous).

Comment: Right, because the inverse image of the open sets in Y-{f(x)} are open in X-{x}.